# How to use development and production environment in NOPCOMMERCE app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis, nopcommerce

I want to know how you manage application in production and development environment. How to publish Source code to IIS Server. How to change something in development and sync it in production environment?

I have No-Source code published in IIS and I don't know how to change something and apply it?

Comment: what was your NOPCOMMERCE app developed using? Usually we use visual studio to publish the developed project to iis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, read nopcommerce documentation:

https://docs.nopcommerce.com/en/developer/tutorials/system-requirements-for-developing.html

Then:

Use Visual Studio 2019, install Web Deploy on your IIS, create a publish profile in Visual studio(one for Dev one for Prod) and use a merge tools(like Diffinity) to sync changing from Dev to Prod; don't sync dataSettings.json(in App_Data) to avoid to publish DEV connection string on PROD.

I hope can be  usefull.